# how to use/implement a custom nodejs Circuit Breaker based on the number of requests?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to figure out  what is the best wait to implement a circuit breaker based of the number of requests been served in a Typescript/express application instead of fails percentage.

Since the application is meant to be executed by large number of users and under a heavy load, I'm trying to customize the response code in order to trigger a horizontal scaling event with k8s/istio.

The first thing I want to start with is to get is the number of requests in nodejs eventloop event if there is some async work in progress, because a big part of my request are executed asynchronously using async/await.

BTW:
I have seen these Libs

- https://github.com/bennadel/Node-Circuit-Breaker
- https://github.com/nodeshift/opossum

Is there any good Idea/path I can start with in order to make this possible ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen that you call a circuit breaker?  Can you provide a mini-spec for what you want?  Add, what's wrong with the libs you've looked at?  And, what does *"trigger a horizontal scaling event with k8s/istio"* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell for sure from your question, but if what you're trying to do is to just keep track of how many requests are in progress and then do something in particular if that number exceeds a particular value, then you can use this middleware:

```
function requestCntr() {
    let inProgress = 0;
    const events = ['finish', 'end', 'error', 'close'];

    return function(req, res, next) {

      function done() {
          // request finished, so decrement the inProgress counter
          --inProgress;
          // unhook all our event handlers so we don't count it more than one
          events.forEach(event => res.off(event, done));
      }

      // increment counter for requests in progress
      ++inProgress;
      const maxRequests = 10;
      if (inProgress > maxRequests) {
          console.log('more than 10 requests in flight at the same time');
          // do whatever you want to here
      }

      events.forEach(event => res.on(event, done));
      next();
    }
}

app.use(requestCntr());
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, a counter for the current requests in progress.
I was looking for a rate limiter more than a circuit breaker.
Once I reach maxRequests I will return 429 HTTP code.  
I will implement something similar to the architecture in this article. 
 https://github.com/stefanprodan/istio-hpa,
Many thanks